# macOS Sierra installation takes forever

Tags: macos

I am trying to install macOS Sierra on my MacBook Pro. The process starts normally until the part when "Install macOS" process starts to download macOS from the App Store.

It seems that there is a connection problem and the download process takes forever (the progress bar does not move even one inch.) I searched around the web and found out by pressing "Command + l" the log window will show. In log window it seems that the "**storedownloadd**" has some difficulties which I don't understand. Here is the log:

```
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Hardware:MacBookPro9,2 @ 2.50 GHz (x 4), 8192 MB RAM
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323)
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Env: DYLD_NO_FIX_PREBINDING=1
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Env: PWD=/
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Env: XPC_FLAGS=0x0
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Env: XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Env: SHLVL=1
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Env: __OSINSTALL_ENVIRONMENT=1
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Env: CI_DEFAULT_OPENCL_USAGE=0
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Env: OS_INSTALL=1
Aug 28 02:57:49 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Env: _=/System/Library/CoreServices/Language Chooser.app/Contents/MacOS/Language Chooser
Aug 28 02:57:51 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: OSISChunkedDownload loaded...
Aug 28 02:57:51 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: OSISAppStoreDownload loaded...
Aug 28 02:57:51 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Bundle path: /Install macOS Sierra.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetupInternal.framework/PlugIns/OSInstallerCompatibility.bundle
Aug 28 02:57:51 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Bundle loaded
Aug 28 02:57:51 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: osinstallersetupd registered client
Aug 28 02:57:51 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Checking Software Update catalog URL https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog
Aug 28 02:57:52 MacBook-Pro Unknown[451]: Aug 28 02:57:52  InstallAssistant[488] <Error>: CGColorSpaceCreateWithName failed for kCGColorSpaceITUR_709
Aug 28 02:57:52 MacBook-Pro Unknown[451]: Aug 28 02:57:52  InstallAssistant[488] <Error>: CGColorSpaceCreateWithName failed for kCGColorSpaceITUR_2020
Aug 28 02:57:52 MacBook-Pro Unknown[451]: Aug 28 02:57:52  InstallAssistant[488] <Error>: CGColorSpaceCreateWithName failed for kCGColorSpaceROMMRGB
Aug 28 02:57:52 MacBook-Pro Unknown[451]: 2018-08-28 02:57:52.865 InstallAssistant[488:16635] NSColorList could not parse color list file /System/Library/Colors/System.clr
Aug 28 02:58:25 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: L8 recovery is older than this version. Trying app store.
Aug 28 02:58:28 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:--------------------------------------------------------- Begin --

       System Version 10.12 (Build 16A323)
       "storeaccountd" Version ? (?)

    -------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 28 02:58:28 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:BagLoadOperation: Attempting to load bag (type=1) from https://init.itunes.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5
Aug 28 02:58:28 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ISStoreURLOperation: Starting URL operation with url=https://init.itunes.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5 / bagKey=(null)
Aug 28 02:58:28 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:-[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation]: _addStandardQueryParametersForURL: https://init.itunes.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5
Aug 28 02:58:36 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:BagController: Asked to invalidate all bags
Aug 28 02:58:37 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:Bag: Successfully updated bag type 1 from https://init.itunes.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5 valid until 2018-08-29 04:58:37 +0000
Aug 28 02:58:37 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:BagLoadOperation: Finished loading bag type 1
Aug 28 02:58:37 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ISStoreURLOperation: Starting URL operation with url=https://xp.apple.com/register / bagKey=(null)
Aug 28 02:58:37 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:-[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation]: _addStandardQueryParametersForURL: https://xp.apple.com/register
Aug 28 02:58:37 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Commerce:--------------------------------------------------------- Begin --

       System Version 10.12 (Build 16A323)
       "osinstallersetupd" Version ? (?)

    -------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 28 02:58:37 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Commerce:ISStoreURLOperation: Starting URL operation with url=(null) / bagKey=preflight-lookup
Aug 28 02:58:37 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Commerce:-[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation]: _addStandardQueryParametersForURL: https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/getPreflight
Aug 28 02:58:38 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ADI: Account is not provisioned, omitting OTP and MD
Aug 28 03:05:45 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Got and processed license agreement message
Aug 28 03:05:46 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: DM ..F-[DMManager(PrivateMethods) clientConforms:error:]: currentThread=4295=0x10c7 expectedThread=775=0x307
Aug 28 03:05:46 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: DM ..F-[DMManager(PrivateMethods) clientConforms:error:]: currentThread=4295=0x10c7 expectedThread=775=0x307
Aug 28 03:05:46 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: DM ..F-[DMManager(PrivateMethods) clientConforms:error:]: currentThread=4295=0x10c7 expectedThread=775=0x307
Aug 28 03:05:46 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: DM ..F-[DMManager(PrivateMethods) clientConforms:error:]: currentThread=4295=0x10c7 expectedThread=775=0x307
Aug 28 03:05:46 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: DM ..F-[DMManager(PrivateMethods) clientConforms:error:]: currentThread=4295=0x10c7 expectedThread=775=0x307
Aug 28 03:06:11 MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[488]: Failed to check if a disk is FDE.
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Helper tool loaded
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Using product <OSISSharedSupportProduct: 0x7f97ae74ab20> at distance 10
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Using product <OSISDefaultRecoveryProduct: 0x7f97ae423f50> at distance 25
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Using product <OSISAppStoreRecoveryProduct: 0x7f97ae52e1a0> at distance 25
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemResources
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.Essentials
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.OSInstall
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.FirmwareUpdate
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.EmbeddedOSFirmware
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: No available package ref for compatibility update. Ignoring.
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: OSISDownloadOperation: totalEstimate=359.000000, significantDownload=1
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:BagLoadOperation: Attempting to load bag (type=1) from https://init.itunes.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ISStoreURLOperation: Starting URL operation with url=https://init.itunes.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5 / bagKey=(null)
Aug 28 03:06:39 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:-[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation]: _addStandardQueryParametersForURL: https://init.itunes.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5
Aug 28 03:06:40 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:--------------------------------------------------------- Begin --

       System Version 10.12 (Build 16A323)
       "storedownloadd" Version ? (?)

    -------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 28 03:06:40 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:DownloadQueue: Setting downloads to paused so user can resume.
Aug 28 03:06:45 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:Bag: Successfully updated bag type 1 from https://init.itunes.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5 valid until 2018-08-28 14:06:45 +0000
Aug 28 03:06:45 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:BagLoadOperation: Finished loading bag type 1
Aug 28 03:06:45 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ISStoreURLOperation: Starting URL operation with url=https://xp.apple.com/register / bagKey=(null)
Aug 28 03:06:45 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:-[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation]: _addStandardQueryParametersForURL: https://xp.apple.com/register
Aug 28 03:06:50 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ADI: Account is not provisioned, omitting OTP and MD
Aug 28 03:06:56 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ADI: Account is not provisioned, omitting OTP and MD
Aug 28 03:07:02 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ADI: Account is not provisioned, omitting OTP and MD
Aug 28 03:07:02 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ADI: Account is not provisioned, omitting OTP and MD
Aug 28 03:07:02 MacBook-Pro storeassetd[499]: Commerce:--------------------------------------------------------- Begin --

       System Version 10.12 (Build 16A323)
       "storeassetd" Version ? (?)

    -------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 28 03:07:02 MacBook-Pro storeassetd[499]: Commerce:SoftwareMap: Running in recovery mode (1) - Disabling all software map sources
Aug 28 03:07:08 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ADI: Account is not provisioned, omitting OTP and MD
Aug 28 03:07:08 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ADI: Account is not provisioned, omitting OTP and MD
Aug 28 03:07:09 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ISStoreURLOperation: Starting URL operation with url=https://play.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZPlay.woa/wa/anonymousFinishProvisioning / bagKey=(null)
Aug 28 03:07:09 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:-[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation]: _addStandardQueryParametersForURL: https://play.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZPlay.woa/wa/anonymousFinishProvisioning
Aug 28 03:07:15 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ADIController: Provisioning completed successfully
Aug 28 03:07:15 MacBook-Pro storeaccountd[494]: Commerce:ADI: Account is provisioned, using OTP and MD from ADI
Aug 28 03:07:16 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Operation queue started
Aug 28 03:07:16 MacBook-Pro osishelperd[502]: Privilaged helper tool loaded.
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Using product PKSecureNetEnabledProduct <file:///Volumes/macOS%2010.13.6%20High%20Sierra/macOS%20Install%20Data/> at distance 5
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemResources
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.Essentials
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.OSInstall
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.FirmwareUpdate
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.EmbeddedOSFirmware
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: No available package ref for compatibility update. Ignoring.
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: OSISDownloadOperation: totalEstimate=382.000000, significantDownload=1
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemResources
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.Essentials
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.OSInstall
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.FirmwareUpdate
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Could not find package ref in any source for: com.apple.pkg.EmbeddedOSFirmware
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: No available package ref for compatibility update. Ignoring.
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[491]: Retrieving 1 packages (5.015 GB)
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storeassetd[499]: Commerce:SoftwareMap: No app was found with bundle ID com.apple.InstallAssistant.Sierra to upgrade to 12.6.03
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:DownloadManifest: removePurgeablePath: /Volumes/macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra/macOS Install Data
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storeassetd[499]: Commerce:SoftwareMap: No app was found with bundle ID com.apple.InstallAssistant.Sierra to upgrade to 12.6.03
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storeassetd[499]: Commerce:SoftwareMap: No app was found with bundle ID com.apple.InstallAssistant.Sierra to upgrade to 12.6.03
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:DownloadOperation: Warning, unable to check disk space recovery requirements for com.apple.InstallAssistant.Sierra (1127487414) because no locally cached preflight was found
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storeassetd[499]: Commerce:SoftwareMap: No app was found with bundle ID com.apple.InstallAssistant.Sierra to upgrade to 12.6.03
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storeassetd[499]: Commerce:SoftwareMap: No app was found with bundle ID com.apple.InstallAssistant.Sierra to upgrade to 12.6.03
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (0.000000)
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:HashedDownloadProvider: Using legacy fairplay stub
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:ISStoreURLOperation: Starting URL operation with url=http://osxapps.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple118/v4/1a/a1/74/1aa174fe-90b0-eb1f-c96a-3c13cf191052/par759846163980697280.pkg / bagKey=(null)
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:-[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation]: _addStandardQueryParametersForURL: http://osxapps.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple118/v4/1a/a1/74/1aa174fe-90b0-eb1f-c96a-3c13cf191052/par759846163980697280.pkg
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:<HashedDownloadProvider: 0x7fd562c3d9e0>: Opening file /Volumes/macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra/macOS Install Data/par759846163980697280.pkg returning file descriptor 3 (0 streamed)
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:AssetDownloadOperation: Subtracted 0 already-downloaded bytes from required space (now requires 5014505266 bytes)
Aug 28 03:07:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:07:20 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:07:21 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:07:23 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:07:24 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:20 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:22 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:30 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:31 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:33 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:34 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:36 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:37 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:39 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:40 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:42 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000000% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:08:43 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:HashedDownloadProvider: Using serial dispatch queue for processing of asset for /Volumes/macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra/macOS Install Data/par759846163980697280.pkg
Aug 28 03:08:43 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (460768.677486)
Aug 28 03:08:45 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (460768.677486)
Aug 28 03:08:47 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (460768.677486)
Aug 28 03:08:48 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (460768.677486)
Aug 28 03:09:07 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (460768.677486)
Aug 28 03:09:08 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (460768.677486)
Aug 28 03:09:10 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (460768.677486)
Aug 28 03:09:11 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (460768.677486)
Aug 28 03:09:13 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:09:14 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:09:16 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:09:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:09:19 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:09:21 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:09:22 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:09:24 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:09:25 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:09:27 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:00 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:01 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:03 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:04 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:06 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:07 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000063% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:09 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:10 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:12 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:14 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:15 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:17 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:20 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:21 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:30 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:32 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:34 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:35 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:37 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (474623.067036)
Aug 28 03:10:38 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:40 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:41 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:43 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:44 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:46 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:10:47 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:14 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:15 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:17 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:18 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:20 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:22 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:23 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:25 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:26 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:28 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:29 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:31 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:32 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000126% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:11:34 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:36 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:37 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:39 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:40 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:42 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:51 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:53 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:54 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:56 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:57 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:11:59 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:12:00 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:12:02 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (461838.840463)
Aug 28 03:12:03 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (-1.000000)
Aug 28 03:12:05 MacBook-Pro storedownloadd[497]: Commerce:sending status (macOS Sierra): 0.000188% (-1.000000)
```

As you can see at the end of log, **storedownloadd** is sending alot of (-1.000000) errors.

My MacBook model (as can be seen in logs) is MacBook Pro 2012. I am booting my laptop from macOS Sierra 10.12 DVD.

Comment: macOS Sierra is not available on DVD media. Is this a DVD with the install software burned onto it? If so, how? What are the steps you're taking to start the installer running from the DVD?

Comment: really? the DVD itself looks semi suspicious to me (no apple logo on it) It was with  my laptop when I bought it from local store. Anyhow I put it in my mac driver and restart my laptop while holding down the "option" key so I can select the DVD as boot device. Then I erased my HD using Disk Utility erase option. After that restore using the DVD. After restarting it needs to connect o internet and I got stuck at "storedownloadd"

Comment: Well, it is suspicious. I think the install process needs to have writable access to the install medium itself, which isn't possible on a DVD, but I may be wrong. I've successfully installed macOS's of many versions from USB thumb drives. This [page at AppleSupport](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) gives details on how to create a bootable thumb drive. You may be able to use the Install app on the DVD to create the thumb drive. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, thank you it worked! I just borrowed a friends mac to create flash disk.

Comment: Expanded on my comment to make it an answer. Please mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the DVD with the macOS Installer app to create a bootable USB thumb drive and install macOS that way. Instructions from Apple are [at this link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

Here's a brief synopsis from this page:

#### Use the 'createinstallmedia' command in Terminal

- After downloading the installer, connect the USB flash drive or other volume that will be used as the bootable installer. Make sure that it has at least 12GB of available storage.
- Open Terminal, which is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.
- Type or paste one of the following commands in Terminal. These assume that the installer is still in your Applications folder, and MyVolume is the name of the USB flash drive or other volume that will be used as the bootable installer. If it has a different name, replace MyVolume accordingly.

High Sierra:

> sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app

Sierra:

> sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app